# Iterating through a bignum - Ruby

Tags: ruby, biginteger, bignum

I have a 309 digit integer, I want to iterate through its characters.

Currently I am using:

```
require 'openssl'
e = 116505013962726356794269846667188147473899121100449069443844506823885859211073843523906823741034558875724969276233769835502344452366515593952571468651971447660633083078837371793388842846199643249996094940742465135064478448126948741186882484457847959126808512823416166517945252986434515406363102297514031583117
```

and I have:

```
e.times do |i|
   ...
end
```

Which, understandably, yields an error:

```
undefined method `times' for #<OpenSSL::BN:0x007fec05002140>
```

I attempted to convert the bignum to an integer:

```
 e.to_i.times do |i|
   ...
 end
```

Which returned:

```
bignum too big to convert into `long'
```

I understand why I am receiving these errors, but I am asking how do I iterate through each character of such a large number?

Comment: Iterating `e` times will take you to the end of times.

Comment: Do you mean "iterate through the digits (as characters) in a base 10 representation" (which the current answer addresses), or something else?

Comment: I don't think it is practical. Even if there were a way to do it, I don't think you would still be alive by the time the iteration finishes.

Comment: There is a bounds, dealing with some crypto things at the moment so I guess iterations this large are common.

Answer (score 3):

How is this ?

```
e = 116505013962726356794269846667188147473899121100449069443844506823885859211073843523906823741034558875724969276233769835502344452366515593952571468651971447660633083078837371793388842846199643249996094940742465135064478448126948741186882484457847959126808512823416166517945252986434515406363102297514031583117
e.to_s.each_char do |c|
    # code
end
```

Comment: Did the trick, thank you!

Comment: There's already an each_char iterator.  e.to_s.each_char{|c| ... }

Comment: @AndyV Thanks for pointing to the correct method... :) For a while I forgot..

Comment: @Derptacos - If this answer was helpful to you, please give it the checkmark.